# Error Inserting values in Dreamer Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'm sorry if this is a simple question but I'm rather new to SQL and I'm having an issue trying to insert some values in a table.

The query I'm executing is the following:

```
INSERT INTO Dreamer VALUES ( 
'', 'Dreamer name', '0', '1554542121', 'pablogardiazabal@gmail.com', 
'Dreamer FB', 'Dreamer TW', 'Dreamer', 'M', '', 0, 0, 'Dreamer DAD', 
'Dreamer MOM', '0', '0', '151515131321', '545343512123', 
'DreamerDAD@daddreamer.com', 'DreamerMOM@momdreamer.com', 
'Dreamer DAD DIR', 'Dreamer MOM DIR', '1515312123123', 
'5456453423', 0)
```

And the table is designed like this:

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjNKw.png) This is the Table

Thanks a lot guys and gals!

EDITTED (sorry about the wrong format)

The error I'm getting is the following

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Put the field names in parenthesis after your table name. Ex: `Insert Into Dreamer (Name, idDocType, etc... ) Values ('', 'Dreamer name', '0', etc...)`

Comment: I keep getting the same error, cant see whats wrong

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Please format your question with code blocks. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Do not include code updates in your comments. If you make changes to your original question, use the edit button to update the question.

Comment: I don't see this field in your table. `IdDmr`

Comment: The values listed don't match up with the table posted. I am not even trying to decipher that comment insert statement.

Comment: I've editted the question with better formatting, the error and a new table screenshot. As you can see, the values correspond to the fields but still fails.

Answer (score 0):

There is mismatch in your order of values, It is better to provide your insert script along with column names and corresponding values as below:

```
INSERT INTO Dreamer (col1, col2...) VALUES (val1,val2...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried this and I keep getting the same error. I'll add a second comment with the code. I can't see what's wrong and it's driving me crazy haha

Comment: I've updated the question with the error and better formatting, sorry if it was misleading

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut to doing the dirty work of comparing every string value in your select list with the definition of the associated column. And you REALLY need to learn how to write literials of a given datatype. '' is not really a valid integer - if you want zero than use the correct literal. And the integer zero is not the same as NULL. Do not start using a bad habit of equating special values with NULL - it will eventually bite you.

The first problem I see is '151515131321' - which is to be assigned to the column DocNumberP : varchar(10). That is more than 10 characters.